# Qt won't connect to a slot in a subclass

Tags: c++, qt

I have subclassed QTabWidget and added a new public slot.  When I try to connect to that slot, Qt tells me that my slot doesn't exist.  But seems to be looking in the parent class.  What am I missing?

Here is a minimal program that reproduces the problem.  I am running it in Qt 5.13 with a MinGW 32-bit package.

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QTabBar>
#include <QDebug>

class MyTabWidget : public QTabWidget
{
public:
    MyTabWidget(QWidget *parent) : QTabWidget(parent)
    {
        qDebug() << "connect() returns " <<
        connect(this->tabBar(),SIGNAL(tabBarDoubleClicked(int)),this,SLOT(changeTabName(int)));
    }

public slots:
    void changeTabName(int index)
    {
        tabBar()->setTabText(index,"New Name");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *mw = new QMainWindow();
    QWidget *tw;

    MyTabWidget *t = new MyTabWidget(mw);
    tw = new QWidget(mw);
    t->addTab(tw,"Double-click This Tab");

    mw->setCentralWidget(t);
    mw->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Here is the output.  When connect() is called, "this" is a pointer to the subclass, right?  So why is it looking for the slot in the superclass?

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QTabWidget::changeTabName(int) in main.cpp:14
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'qt_tabwidget_tabbar')
connect() returns  false
```

Comment: Your `MyTabWidget` class is missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it instantly.  Thanks!  Out of curiosity, why are you commenting instead of posting this as an answer?

Comment: This probably should be a duplicate or even a typo

Comment: @transconductance The reason for not posting as an answer is that I was sure there'd be a duplicate of this somewhere.  Anyway, an answer has been posted so all's well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following errors:

- If a class that inherits from QObject like all widgets is going to have signals, slots, etc. then you must use the Q_OBJECT macro to create the necessary implementations associated with those elements. Therefore, if you are using Q_OBJECT in the main file (filename.cpp) then you must include "filename.moc" to include the above.
- You must use the new connection syntax, although it is not an error but can be a source of silent bugs.

Considering the above, the solution is:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QTabBar>
#include <QDebug>

class MyTabWidget : public QTabWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTabWidget(QWidget *parent) : QTabWidget(parent)
    {
        qDebug() << "connect() returns " <<
        connect(tabBar(), &QTabBar::tabBarDoubleClicked, this, &MyTabWidget::changeTabName);
    }

public slots:
    void changeTabName(int index)
    {
        tabBar()->setTabText(index,"New Name");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *mw = new QMainWindow();
    QWidget *tw;

    MyTabWidget *t = new MyTabWidget(mw);
    tw = new QWidget(mw);
    t->addTab(tw,"Double-click This Tab");

    mw->setCentralWidget(t);
    mw->show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: I was confused by your "new connect syntax" because, from what I've read, that is exactly the "old" connect syntax and the way I did it is the "new" way.  However, I looked it up again and you are correct, the SIGNAL and SLOT macros are the "old" way.

Comment: @transconductance read more in  https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax